# How do I send a value of a variable from view to form in django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want a customized dropdown list as a choice field for a variable.
This list depends on another variable in form
How can I send a variable value to the variable in forms

views.py

```
somelist= ['blah','blah1']   
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name='charts.html'


def get(self, request):
    form = HomeForm()

    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})
def post(self,request):
    form=HomeForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        text_11 = form.cleaned_data['post11']
        global e
        e=text_11
        text_1 = form.cleaned_data['post_1']
        global z
        z=text_1
        text = form.cleaned_data['post']
        global b
        b=text
        text1 = form.cleaned_data['post1']
        global c
        c=text1
        text2 = form.cleaned_data['post2']
        global d
        d=text2
    args = {'form':form, 'text_11':text_11,'text_1':text_1,'text':text, 'text1':text1, 'text2':text2}
    return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

my forms.py

```
class HomeForm(forms.Form):
      post11=forms.ChoiceField(choices=((None,None),('लिंग :','sex :'),('शिक्षण:','education:')))

      post_1 = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,choices=**somelist**) 
      post = forms.ChoiceField(choices=((None,None),('लिंग :','लिंग :'),('शिक्षण:','शिक्षण:'),('जात :','जात :'))) 
      post1 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=((None,None),('लिंग :','लिंग :'),('शिक्षण:','शिक्षण:'))) 
      post2 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=((None,None),('bar','bar'),('horizontalBar','horizontalBar')))
```

I want the variable to be here

```
post_1 = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,choices=**somelist**)
```

PS: I don't want to set a field variable, I want to set the choices of a field variable
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you know what is `**somelist**` ?

Comment: yes, But it changes everytime

Answer (score 0):

form = HomeForm(initial={'z':z})

Comment: I used the above thing in get function.
and then directly used the z variable in choices of a choicefield.
it gives me an error saying 'z' not defined.


Do tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You edited z to now be somelist= ['blah','blah1'] in your view


that would change

form = HomeForm(initial={'somelist':somelist})

the point I was making is you can pass an initial value(s) over in this way to use in your form

Comment: It gives me this error
post_1 = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,choices=somelist).    
NameError: name 'somelist' is not defined